# Inverse function, domain and range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm delving into some further algebra as I prepare for the GRE in 2017!

This practice question is causing me trouble:

> The function $f(x)$ is defined by: $f(x) = x^2 - 6x + 13$, $x\in \Bbb R$, $x\ge 3$.
>   Obtain the inverse function, stating its domain and range.

So first, I'm right in thinking that the inverse function will be the same as the domain of the original function?

Comment: You mean the *range* of the inverse function will be the same as the domain of the original function.

Comment: In general, $\operatorname{Domain}(f) = \operatorname{Range}(f^{-1})$ and $\operatorname{Range}(f) = \operatorname{Domain}(f^{-1})$.

Comment: So far I have switched f(x) and y to give me y = x^2 - 6x + 13 and then I've switched x and y to give me x = y^2 - 6y + 13

Comment: Next I will solve for y......which becomes difficult with two y's. Should I have left x^2 as it was?

Comment: Okay so now I've left x^2 in and have arrived at 6y = x^2 + 13 -x

Comment: No.  You want to have $x=y^2-6y+13$.  Then complete the square, take the square root, and decide, using what you know about the graph of inverse functions, whether to take the positive or negative root.

Comment: Which means y is equal to x^2 + 13 - x all divided by 6.

And this is the inverse function, which the notation f^-1(x)

Comment: You can't just pick and choose which $x$'s to switch with $y$'s.  All $x$'s $\to$ $y$'s and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think the square can be completed with that equation? I've tried to find the correct coefficient.

Comment: I think solving for y is the correct way to go

Comment: You definitely can complete the square, as I did in my answer.  If you're not sure *how to* complete the square you should go back to that section of your text and work through a bunch of problems until you've got it down.

Comment: I'll do this, thanks for your help Bye_World

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's get a bearing on $f$.  To do so we'll graph it.  The function $$x\mapsto x^2-6x+13$$ looks like this

[image]

But the function $f$ has a restricted domain, so let's see which part of this graph remains when we consider only $x\ge 3$.

[image]

Notice that this function is strictly increasing (and thus invertible).

---

Now we'll switch the $x$ and $y$ in this equation and see if we can't find an expression for the inverse:

$$x=y^2-6y+13 \\ x= (y-3)^2-9+13 \\ x=(y-3)^2+4 \\ \pm\sqrt{x-4}=y-3 \\ y=3\pm\sqrt{x-4}$$

[image]

Notice that this is not a function because it is multivalued everywhere in its domain except right at $x=4$.  So we'll need to choose the correct branch of this function (by taking either the $+$ or $-$ sign in the above equation) given the restriction we had for the domain of $f$.

---

Now we recall that the inverse of a function looks graphically like the function reflected over the line $y=x$.  Confirm for yourself that if you reflect $f$ over that line you get the upper part of the graph of $y=3\pm\sqrt{x-4}$.  Thus the inverse function is $f^{-1}(x) = 3\color{red}{+} \sqrt{x-4}$.

---

Now let's consider the domain and range of both functions.  The domain of $f$ is given in the question: $D(f) = \{x\mid x\ge 3\}$.  The range is easy enough to get from the graph.  Notice the lowest point on the graph is $(3,4)$ and then it increases without bound.  So the range is $R(f) = \{y\mid y\ge 4\}$.

The inverse function should be the opposite of this.  Meaning the range (domain) of $f$ should be the domain (range) of $f^{-1}$.  So let's see.  We can see the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $D(f^{-1}) = \{x\mid x\ge 4\}$.  It would have been easier to see graphically if WolframAlpha had been more accommodating, but you can see why it must be this -- the $\sqrt{x-4}$ part is undefined for $x<4$.  Then, remembering we're only taking the upper branch of the graph above, we see that $f^{-1}$ is an increasing function just like $f$ was.  Its lowest point is $(4,3)$ (just plug in $x=4$ to see $y=3$) and it increases without bound from there.  So $R(f^{-1}) = \{y\mid y\ge 3\}$ as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time, you managed to crack my mind. I've got it. Super appreciative of you.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple honestly, for this particular equation you can swap $x$ and $y$, and once you get $x=y^2-6y+13$, you solve the equation for $y$, and there you have it, you have the answer.

Comment: I'm keen to have a go myself, I just don't know how to get the y out of the y^2. Is this where the completion of the square comes in?

Comment: Which gives (y-3)^2 + 4

Comment: You can simply solve it with a Quadratic formula, ax^2+bx+c=0

Comment: Oh well, look like somebody did it for ya)